# How do I get the class of a ManyToMany field in django models?

Tags: python, django-models

I have some fields in a model that are ManyToMany, I want the ManyToMany class itself, when I only have the field name. Is there any way I can retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `model_obj` were an instance of the Model class that defines a ManyToManyField named `foom2m`, then you could do this:

```
related_model = model_obj.__class_.foom2m.field.rel.to
```